# Installing twisted in shared hosting

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, twisted

I am trying to install twisted in my shared hosting and ended up with this error.

```html
unable to execute gcc: Permission denied
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I contacted my provider and they confirmed they cannot install it.

Is there any manual way of installing using the source file. I am able to download the package using wget.

Now I have folder with name  "Twisted-17.9.0", Is there any way install using source files.

My hosted server is of Cento OS

Comment: Try using `virtualenv` and see if that helps you install it locally https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv. Given that you can install virtualenv

Comment: I created a virtual env called Proj and installing there .and failed with the above error

Comment: You should get a VPS from some other cloud provider then. Shared hosting are always restrictive